# How to create a filter based on what I selected in multiple drop-down lists?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have about 15 drop-downs and I want to return the objects in the database that are equal to those selected in the drop-down. I managed to display the data in drop-downs with Thymeleaf and Spring and then I made a POST request where I received what I have selected. I do not know how to do, with jpa, the methods in the warehouses that give me the objects from the database.

The controller

```
@GetMapping("/filter/functionality/misramessages")
    public String filterFunctionality(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("misraMessages", misraMessagesService.findAllMisraMessagesFromDb());
        model.addAttribute("mistraObjectSelected", new MisraMessages());

        return "functionality";
    }

    @PostMapping("/filter/functionality/misramessages")
    public String getFilterFunctionalityResult(@PathVariable(name = "buidId", required=false) Build buildId,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "fileName", required=false) String fileName,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "filePath", required=false) String filePath,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "messageNumber", required=false) String messageNumber,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "messageSeverity", required=false) String messageSeverity,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "guidelineNumber", required=false) String guidelineNumber,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "guidelineName", required=false) String guidelineName,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "guidelineType", required=false) String guidelineType,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "guidelineSeverity", required=false) String guidelineSeverity,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "requirement", required=false) String requirement,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "sourceCodeCategory", required=false) String sourceCodeCategory,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "safety", required=false) String safety,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "functionality", required=false) String functionality,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "subFunctionality", required=false) String subFunctionality,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "applicationType", required=false) String applicationType,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "supplier", required=false) String supplier,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "cmVersion", required=false) String cmVersion,
                                               @RequestParam(name = "asilLevel", required=false) String asilLevel) {


 }
```

Drop-downs

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/filter/result}" method="post">

        <!-- Filter Build-->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="build" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Build</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control"  name="buildId" id="build">
                    <option th:value="0" text="Please Select"></option>
                    <option  th:each = "misra : ${misraMessages}"
                             th:value="${misra.buildId.buildId}"
                             th:text="${misra.buildId.buildId}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Filter File Name-->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fileName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control"  name="fileName" id="fileName">
                    <option th:value="0" text="Please Select"></option>
                    <option  th:each = "misra : ${misraMessages}"
                             th:value="${misra.fileName}"
                             th:text="${misra.fileName}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
           ..........
           ..........
           ..........
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandra! So what you need to know, is how to make a query to your database with the corresponding filters? If so, are you using any ORM (Object-relation mapping) tool, like Hibernate?

Comment: Hello! I'm using JPA, and my problem is how to generate the querry, because I have like 17 fields, and can have multiple combination, like as : findByFileName(), fileByFileNameAndFilePath(), findByFileNameAndBuildId()... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is too broad, I can't provide you specific answer but I will try to give you general idea.

First you need to understand how `JPA` works. Decide what you want to use for eg. hibernate, spring data, jdbc, mybatis etc... You can find a lot of tutorials out there on internet on how to use `JPA`.

First you need to create  a `POJO` class with all attributes.  This `POJO` class is Something like this

```
public class MyClass{

private String filename;
private String filePath;
...
//getters setters
}
```

I would combine all `RequestParam` as `map`. This is not required but makes your code clean because you have a lot of `RequestParam`.

```
 @PostMapping("/filter/functionality/misramessages")
        public String getFilterFunctionalityResult(@PathVariable(name = "buidId", required=false) Build buildId,@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams){
// your code here
}
```

Now you can set all the `RequestParam` values to `POJO`

```
Myclass myClass = new Myclass();
myclass.setFileName(requestParams.get("fileName"));
...
```

you have to create  `@Service` and `@Repository` classes that will handle all your service layer logic and logic to interactwith database. 
There are perfect examples on [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). Try to spend some time there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I did  how you wrote me, but my problem is how to create the querry because I have like 17 fields, and can have multiple combination, like as : findByFileName(), fileByFileNameAndFilePath(), findByFileNameAndBuildId()... etc

Comment: you can have multiple queries. That is totally fine.